# Multiple Django sites on the same domain - CSRF fails

Tags: django, cookies, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I have two applications running on the same domain on different ports, both using csrf middleware.

When I log-in in one of the applications all `POST` submits from the other fail.
I presume because the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` is the same.

I tried changing `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`, however, the `'csrftoken'` cookie is used in the forms `POST` request on both sites, no matter that there now is a new cookie with the name I specified.

When I post information with AJAX and get the csrf token from the cookie with the new name - it works, however, form submits fail with CSRF verification failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSRF token cookie is named csrftoken by default, but you can control the cookie name via the CSRF_COOKIE_NAME setting. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Use a different CSRF cookie name for each app.

Comment: the AJAX works when I change the cookie name, the html form POST requests do not

Comment: You said you only changed the SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, but did you also change the CSRF_COOKIE_NAME as I mentioned? Are you forms including the {% csrf_token %} tag?

Comment: well, sir, SESSION_COOKIE_NAME and CSRF_COOKIE_NAME were different things. you saved me. thanks!

Comment: It is worth specifically noting that both `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` and `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` both need to be changed.