# How to deal with two websites with one backend CSRF issue in one browser?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

How to deal with the independent home website and admin website CSRF issue in one browser?

We have written a home website frontend and an admin website frontend for it (there are **two** frontends), using JavaScript in the frontend.
Because both sites are large, we have put them as vhost in Nginx. They are two sites. I use Python (Django) to write **one** backend, both sites invoke one backend.

The home website uses Nginx's `default.conf`, the admin website uses `vhosts/admin.conf`.

This is the test domain:

`http://www.ajw123.xyz` as the home website.
  `http://admin.ajw123.xyz` as the admin website.

My trouble is when I use an account login on the home website in the browser:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Then I use the account to login to the admin website (or other accounts), the CSRF Token Error is thrown:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see the `csrftoken` both are:

```
csrftoken=L5bRGEXDvW9dJaXsanLlMTOrxxGpxJCw6vji1zQtjzYrskOq0FBjQtfkhvFKFDmj;
```

In the preview:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.

I use Django-Rest-Framework for the rest APIs, our frontend colleagues write two sites (one is normal user frontend and backend site, the other is admin's backend site), and both are using my rest APIs.

Comment: Use different cookie name on each one

Comment: @charlietfl How to do with that? do you mean in Nginx?

Comment: In whatever Django module that manages the csrf. i'm not a django dev but have done this in other environments

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you anyway.

Comment: Why do you need two different sites? Wouldn't it be better to have 1 (**one**) Django project with 2 (**two**) (or maybe more) different apps?

Comment: @cezar I use Django-Rest-Framework write the rest APIs, our frontend colleagues write two site, and all use my one rest APIs project.

Comment: This is very important information you omitted in your question. So basically your Django project is a  REST API. The frontends (home and admin) are clients consuming the API. Right? Did you read [this page of the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/)?

Comment: @cezar, Thank you. I use CORS config my `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` then solved my problem. Can you answer the post, then I select your answer? Thank you again, my friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is in my opininon an example of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). In the following text I'll come back to my claim and explain it.

The OP has written a REST API using Django REST Framework. Omitting this information initially led to very low attention. After including this information the thing became much clearer.

Let's first recall some basics about REST APIs. A REST API is language agnostic. It doesn't care in which language the clients are written, and also the clients don't care in which language the API has been written. The REST API can be accessed (consumed) in different ways: from the command line using `curl`; from a script written in any programming language; from a browser using (most likely) JavaScript (or a JavaScript framework).

Since there are two websites consuming the API, the OP wanted to provide them access to the API. The obstacle that has arisen was CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery).
Django has implemented CSRF protection with the use of CSRF tokens. This means we protect our website from requests from other websites, where usually a form can be posted to our website.

In the actuall case the clients are two different websites hosted on different domains, so the requests coming from them are from a different site. What the OP really wants to know is:
*"How to grant or restrict access to other websites consuming my API?"*
and not:
*"How to deal with the CSRF issue?"*

The official documentation of Django REST Framwork has a page dedicated to this issue:
[Working with AJAX, CSRF & CORS](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/)

This is the section for CORS:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a mechanism for allowing clients to interact with APIs that are hosted on a different domain. CORS works by requiring the server to include a specific set of headers that allow a browser to determine if and when cross-domain requests should be allowed.
>
> The best way to deal with CORS in REST framework is to add the required response headers in middleware. This ensures that CORS is supported transparently, without having to change any behavior in your views.
>
> Otto Yiu maintains the django-cors-headers package, which is known to work correctly with REST framework APIs.

I'll emphasise the first sentence:

> **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a mechanism for allowing clients to interact with APIs that are hosted on a different domain.**

Exactly that is the case. The OP wants to allow clients to interact with his API that is hosted on a different domain.
The last sentence recommends the use of `django-cors-headers` which is the solution of the problem.
All further details about the use of the app can be found in its documentation.

Answer (score 3):

CSRF token is essentially a cookie which is retrievable.
By default, the name of this cookie is `csrftoken` for every django app.

You need to change the name of at least one of the cookies with the `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` setting (in your `settings.py`).

Then your colleagues can retrieve that cookie with the following AJAX call:

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('name_of_your_token');
```

For more complicated uses check the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/

---

A similar case: [Multiple Django sites on the same domain - CSRF fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902243/multiple-django-sites-on-the-same-domain-csrf-fails)

Comment: Do you mean just change the cookie name in frontend? should I config in the DRF backend?

Comment: @aircraft You need to configure the DRF backend to add different names to your `csrf` cookies. Your colleagues need to refactor their site to use those cookies. (you can also test them with what is presented in the linked documentation)

Comment: I read the doc about `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`, but you should pay attention my situation is:  in one browser. there are two frontend site, both use one django backend. if I set `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`, is it both frontend `csrftoken` name all changed?

Comment: @aircraft Yes in that case (you added that info after I posted my answer btw) you don't need to change the name of the `csrftoken`. You only need your frontend(s) to access it directly as shown above and in the documentation.

Comment: no matter change the `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` in my settings, but both website all are still using my one Django backend. How can I distinguish the two site? my DRF backend just provide APIs, and the two site are write by vus.js(you can think they are html+javascript). If as your method, this is just both site change a `csrf_token` (name) to  other name. this can not distinguish the two site `csrf_token`.

Comment: @aircraft As `cezar` said, have you read the documentation? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/

Comment: I paid tribute to your answer as it shows how to deal with the CSRF token with multiple sites. However I think it is an XY problem and this is an answer to Y and posted an own answer as requested by the OP.

Comment: @cezar Seems possible mate!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @cezar and @JohnMoutafis, I read the doc of [CORS](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors):

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a mechanism for allowing clients to interact with APIs that are hosted on a different domain. CORS works by requiring the server to include a specific set of headers that allow a browser to determine if and when cross-domain requests should be allowed.

Then I installed the `django-cors-headers`, and use it.

I set the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://10.10.10.102:8000', # normal user site
    'http://10.10.10.102:8080', # admin backend site
)
```

Now it works fine.

Thank you again.

Comment: There you go! You have the answer and the solution.

Comment: @cezar The answer is you and JohnMoutafis' contribution. Can you post your answer there then I select your answer, because I don't want to waste the bounty.